# ajax request not loading because server side php file not available

Tags: php, ajax

ajax request test. my question is ... where the test.php should be in server in order to be found by url:"test.php"?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" onclick="create()">Click Me</button>


    <script>
    function create () {
          $.ajax({
            url:"test.php", //the page containing php script
            type: "post", //request type,
            dataType: 'json',
           data: {reg: "success", name: "bnm", email: "lolo@gmail.com"}
            success:function(result){

             console.log(result.abc);
           }
         });
     }
<script>
```

On the server side test.php file

```
$regstration = $_POST['reg'];
$name= $_POST['name'];
$email= $_POST['email'];

if ($registration == "success"){
 // some action goes here under php
 echo json_encode(array("abc"=>'successfuly registered'));
}
```

Comment: `$regstration = $_POST['reg'];` missspelled... could that prove to be problematic for the condition `if ($registration == "success"){`?

Answer (score 0):

it should be placed in the same path as your form. You have errors in your code.
Try this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="create()">Click Me</button>
<script>
  function create() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php", //the page containing php script
      type: "post", //request type,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        reg: "success",
        name: "bnm",
        email: "lolo@gmail.com"
      },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result.abc);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksiger/4sug03wa/5/)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @stefanosn try to print some message in `test.php` without any conditions and get this file from browser. Just write it in address line without using js.

Comment: this is what i am trying now... i get not found every time. i use wordpress , do i have to put it some other place? its in the same place where content-single.php exists

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195718/discussion-between-ksiger-and-stefanosn).

Answer (score 0):

if you have the `test.php` file in the same path as your form, for example:

**test.php**

```
http://localhost/demo/test.php
```

**form.html**

```
http://localhost/demo/form.html
```

But if you need to do a request to `test.php` file from another path, you need to add a slash in url and then the file name, like this `/demo/test.php`;

Comment: plase send the ajax response screenshot

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)